# How to configure adaptive bitrate in VLC-android

Tags: android, vlc, libvlc, adaptive-bitrate, vlc-android

Im trying to build https://github.com/videolan/vlc-android using Android Studio and I was successful in doing that and able to play a youtube video using it.

However I have noticed that the playback starts in low bitrate and it scales up(I could see the video quality changing).

How to start the streaming in higher bit rate? I tried setting 'preferred_resolution' as 1080 but no luck . Is there a way to configure this? Any help/input will be really helpful.

PS:- Please let me know if any other input is needed from my end.